# Cannot convert 'labels' from dataset catalogue into a Numpy array in TensorFlow (in Python)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I have the 'bccd' dataset with the following info:

```
Width x Height : 640 x 480',
    homepage='https://github.com/Shenggan/BCCD_Dataset',
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'image': Image(shape=(480, 640, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
        'image/filename': Text(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
        'objects': Sequence({
            'bbox': BBoxFeature(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32),
            'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=3),
        }),
    }),
```

i want to access 'label' as a numpy array,
I am using the following code:

```
builder = tfds.builder('bccd')
info = builder.info
x = info.features["objects"]["label"]
ds_train = tfds.load(name="bccd", split="train")

train_labels = np.array([example[x].numpy()[:,:,0] for example in ds_train])
```

However the last code is throwing an error that says

> KeyError: ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=3)

I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: `x` isn't what you think it is

Comment: Could you share the sample dataset. Thanks